# jGrowl add and remove notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, jgrowl

I am not able to remove the jGrowl notification.

Add:

```
$.jGrowl(text, {  sticky: true,  header: header, theme: 'aa', growlId: tag});
```

Remove:

```
$("div#" + tag).trigger("jGrowl.close").remove();
```

For adding, I am seting "growlId" and using that growlId to remove it. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Anyone who used jGrowl ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above code is that there is no property 'growlId' in the jGrowl options object.  So the id of the node you are referencing most likely does not exist.  If it did, the jGrowl.close event would be enough, as it does remove() the node it is triggered on.  See:
https://github.com/stanlemon/jGrowl/blob/master/jquery.jgrowl.js#L278

If you want to remove the last notification raised, simply do this:

```
$('.jGrowl-notification:last').trigger('jGrowl.close');
```

If you want to remove all jGrowl notifications, you could do:

```
$('.jGrowl-notification').trigger('jGrowl.close');
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I used http://moonlitscript.com/post.cfm/jgrowl-modification/ this example. I am trying to close specific jGrowl.

Comment: Found the solution. Topic close.